# Compress bitmap with GZipStream

Tags: c#

I`m trying to compress a bitmap image but the output stream is always empty.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
public static byte[] CompressBitmap (Bitmap img)
    {
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream ())
        {
            // Compress image
            using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream (outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                // Convert image into memory stream and compress
                using (MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream ())
                {
                    img.Save (imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);                                                        
                    imgStream.CopyTo (zipStream);
                    return outputStream.ToArray ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I changed a little bit and seems like its working:

```
public static byte[] CompressBitmap (Bitmap img)
    {
        // Convertendo bitmap para memory stream
        using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream ())
        {
            // Para evitar memory leak
            using (img) 
            {
                img.Save(inStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }

            // Salva stream no array de byte
            byte[] buffer = new byte[inStream.Length];
            inStream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Comprime bitmap
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    gzipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    return outStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

But now, the decompress is wrong:

```
public static Bitmap DecompressBitmap (byte[] compressed)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream (compressed))
            {
                using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream (inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    // Decompress image and convert to bitmap
                    using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream ())
                    {
                        zipStream.CopyTo (outputStream);
                        return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream (zipStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compress an already compressed image?

Comment: Because i was filling out the compressed image parameter on my webservice. To avoid fill with a bitmap, i realized that can be better if I pass a byte array (instead of a base64string to that is too big)

Comment: That logic you explained does not make sense.

Comment: Actually i was thinking: "which solution is better to fill out a parameter throw a webservice?" so i was thinking in convert a bitmap into a base64string, but its too large. And then, now im trying to test a compressed bitmap and pass a byte array to the WS. What u guys think? Not a good idea?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the difference between encoding and compression.

Comment: But bitmap is not compressed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: You are saving it as a JPEG which is a (lossy) compressed format. PNG is just a BMP that has been GZipped.

Comment: But when i save i just do img.Save(); and it saves in BMP format

Comment: No, you are not according to the code you pasted...

Comment: It's because that was an error xD atuaclly the correct was:

Comment: img.Save (imgStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

Comment: You should edit your post then (If you can't, ask me ;p)

Comment: Done! Sry dude... and thanks for all the help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if you are needing to definitely convert the BMP to a JPEG or not. If you just want to compress it, store it, and be able to uncompress it, this will help you. I tested with a small screenshot on my local machine and it shrunk from 2.8MB to 19KB and I was able to open it with this code and using 7zip.

```
void Main()
{
    //set some test paths
    string originalfilepath = @"c:\temp\screenshot.bmp";
    string decompressedfilepath = @"c:\temp\screenshot.bmp.gz.bmp";
    string compressedfilepath = @"c:\temp\screenshot.bmp.gz";

    //read in the original file, this byte array could come from anywhere
    byte[] originalfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(originalfilepath);
    Console.WriteLine("original array size {0} bytes (as read from original file)",originalfilebytes.Length);

    //compress it
    byte[] compressedfilebytes = Compress(originalfilebytes);
    Console.WriteLine("compressed array size {0} bytes",compressedfilebytes.Length);

    //write it out so we can see it and test the compression with 7zip etc
    File.WriteAllBytes(compressedfilepath,compressedfilebytes);

    //write over our compressed bytes array by reading in the compressed file just to test
    compressedfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(compressedfilepath);
    Console.WriteLine("compressed array size {0} bytes (as read from compressed file)",compressedfilebytes.Length);

    //decompress the array
    byte[] decompressedfilebytes = Decompress(compressedfilebytes);
    Console.WriteLine("decompressed array size {0} bytes",decompressedfilebytes.Length);

    //write it to yet another file just to be sure decompress works
    File.WriteAllBytes(decompressedfilepath,decompressedfilebytes);
}
byte[] Compress(byte[] b)
{
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream z = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        z.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
}
byte[] Decompress(byte[] b)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var bs = new MemoryStream(b))
        using (var z = new GZipStream(bs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            z.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roy! I will try to use this method!

Comment: My pleasure. Hope it works for you. If it works for you please mark this as answered so it will filter out of the unanswered list. =)